# MySQL Error: #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql

I want to update an auto increment b_id based on column house_id example:

id  house_id  b_id

```
+-------------------+
|  1   |  H1  |  1  |
|  2   |  H1  |  2  |
|  3   |  H1  |  3  |
|  4   |  H2  |  1  |
|  5   |  H3  |  1  |
+-------------------+
```

Tried with this code and successfully generated the b_id but does not update the table.

```
SELECT t.id,
       house_id, 
       (SELECT count(*) 
        FROM House 
        WHERE house_id = t.house_id 
          AND id <= t.id
       ) AS b_id 
FROM House t
```

So i tried with this code:

```
UPDATE House 
SET b_id = (SELECT t.id, 
                   house_id, 
                   (SELECT count(*) 
                    FROM House 
                    WHERE house_id = t.house_id 
                      AND id <= t.id
                   ) AS b_id 
            FROM House t);
```

But there is error #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s).

I explore on internet, but do not really understand and cannot related with my sql code. Any idea?

Comment: In your select statement you have both `t.id` and `house_id`. For updating a single column, you can't assign two values to it. You should have only single value in your inner select statement which can be assigned to `b_id`

Comment: Does it mean, i have to remove `t.id` and `house.id` from first SELECT statement? @KrishnaRaniSahoo

Comment: Yes. They are not needed in update statement

Comment: Ok, i already try with this code : `UPDATE House 
SET b_id = (
    SELECT 
    (SELECT count(*) 
    FROM House 
    WHERE 
        house_id = t.house_id 
        AND id <= t.id
    ) AS b_id 
FROM House t);` but there is another mysql error : _Subquery returns more than 1 row_  @KrishnaRaniSahoo.

Comment: Its because for each row it is returning more than 1 values. So you should implement JOIN query. use ` (
    SELECT 
    t.id, house_id, 
    (SELECT count(*) 
    FROM House 
    WHERE 
        house_id = t.house_id 
        AND id <= t.id
    ) ` as temp table within the query and update with the `house.b_id with temp_table.id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having 3 columns in your `select` to update a single column and that is why you are getting error. You can use `Joins` for your `update`. If you are using MYSQL `8.0` you can use below query to update the count.

```
UPDATE
    house AS h
JOIN
    (SELECT id, house_id, row_number() over (partition by house_id) as cnt 
     from house) AS g
    on g.id =h.id
SET 
    h.b_id = g.cnt ;
```

[**Check Demo here**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=535f8e416af1e67cdb51e7d7f3edbab9)

Also i have changed your query using `joins`

```
UPDATE
    house AS p
JOIN 
    (SELECT t.id,(SELECT count(*) FROM house 
                   WHERE house_id = t.house_id 
                    AND id <= t.id) AS b_id 
     FROM house t) AS g
ON p.id = g.id
SET 
    p.b_id = g.b_id ;
```

[**Demo with your query**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c21953d4a94751bedb2b23cb0b91714d)

Comment: I try implement the code. But then the b_id have the same value instead of auto-increment. @Arun Palanisamy

Comment: @Malca , I have updated my answer. You can use the first one if you are using `MySQL 8.0` and above. Otherwise you can use the second one.

Comment: Thank you so much for clear explanation both answer and demo. I use second one because incase i need to add another data and generate b_id. But first one also good to learn using row_number(). Thank you again @ArunPalanisamy.